# Tomcat - port and url changes when accessing the deployed application

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

Good day!

I have successfully installed tomcat, started it, and can reach the tomcat page via localhost:8080.

Before I run the startup.bat, I placed a web application foo in the webapps folder. Now, the problem is when I am trying to access the said web application let's say http://localhost:8080/foo the URL changes to https://localhost:8443/foo/ and the page tells that the site can't be reached and that the localhost refused to connect. This is driving me crazy! Would anyone have any idea about this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like HTTPS is simply not activated in your Tomcat installation, or is not setup for port 8443. http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html and https://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-support-ssl-or-https/

Comment: Hi @Gimby. I am a litte hesitant to do this because I checked the server.xml file of the tomcat in a working Vitual Machine and the configuration is not touched. I guess this would not be the error? I am trying to replicate and create a new workspace because the VM is so slow.

Comment: The configuration may be unchanged, but if you actually go look at the urls I provided rather than being hesitant, you'll see that a requirement is to install a certificate to make HTTPS work. That is completely isolated from the Tomcat installation - that's a Java runtime setup step.

Comment: Have a look in WEB-INF/web.xml, for an element called "<security constraint ../>" and if it contains "<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>".

Comment: Hi @Gimby, are you talking about the "Installing a Certificate from a Certificate Authority" section of the Apache SSL HOW-TO page? this section is really unclear to me. Can you further explain? Sorry.

Comment: Hi @Stefan, in case this configuration is present in the web.xml, what should be done? Thanks a lot.

Comment: In that case http will be redirected to https. You might delete that config (or comment it for development), or you need to setup a [https connector](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Edit_the_Tomcat_Configuration_File) in Tomcat listening to port 8443.

Comment: Thank you @Gimby and Stefan it is now working. Both of your answers are correct. The problem now is how can I credit you both? :S

Answer (score 0):

Your `foo` application contains a redirect URL for authentication like `CAS`.

Check `foo` application configuration.

Comment: Hmm can you tell me where this configuration probably is? The application was just passed with no proper turnover :(

Comment: Port 8443 implies just HTTPS, not authentication or CAS.